# Julia prints different results when calculating with variables

Tags: boolean, julia, bitarray

The problem is difficult to describe (hence the bad titel), it is easier to show it:

```
matr =
[
1 1 3
2 1 10
3 2 3
13 8 10]

i=1

print(matr[:,2].==i .* matr[:,3].!=i)
x = matr[:,2].==i
y = matr[:,3].!=i
print(x .* y)
```

The first and the second print() should be equivalent. Regardless, the first one prints `Bool[false, false, false, false]` the second one prints `Bool[true, true, false, false]`.

Since the first result is wrong, I am wondering how this problem arises and how it can be prevented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [operator precedence](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/index.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity-1) issue. What you write in the first `print` is not what you intended.

```
print(matr[:,2].==i .* matr[:,3].!=i)
```

This is equivalent to *(see the parentheses)*

```
print(matr[:,2] .== (i .* matr[:,3]) .!=i)
```

which is a [chaining comparison](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/index.html#Chaining-comparisons-1), so that both `matr[k,2] == (i .* matr[k,3]))` and `matr[k,2] == (i .* matr[k,3]))` must be true for the `k`th index in order for the chaining comparison to return `true` for the `k`th index.

Instead you can write the same term with explicit parentheses to take care of the precedence issue.

```
print((matr[:,2].==i) .* (matr[:,3].!=i))
```

Instead of multiplication, you can broadcast `&`.

```
print((matr[:,2].==i) .& (matr[:,3].!=i))
```

Both of these should give you the right answer.